# How to remove duplicate rows in Google BigQuery based on a unique identifier

Tags: google-bigquery

In SQL, I use the following code to remove duplicates from a table based on a unique ID:

```
1. SELECT Unique_ID INTO holdkey FROM [Origination] GROUP BY Unique_ID HAVING count(*) > 1

2. SELECT DISTINCT Origination.*
INTO holddups
FROM [Origination], holdkey
WHERE [Origination].Unique_ID = holdkey.Unique_ID

3. DELETE Origination 
FROM Origination, holdkey
WHERE Origination.Unique_ID = holdkey.Unique_ID

4. INSERT Origination SELECT * FROM holddups
```

The second process does not work on BigQuery. Regardless of how I change the query, I get errors for unrecognized columns and tables.

I obviously take out "select into" queries and just set the destination tables manually. I have SQL experience, and I know the process works. Does anyone have a sample of syntax that they use for the process of removing duplicate records based on a unique ID for BQ? Or a way to modify this that would make it run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the trick is in having proper `SELECT` here

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT row[OFFSET(0)].* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1) row
  FROM `project.dataset.table_with_dups` t
  GROUP BY id
)
```

you can test / play with above using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table_with_dups` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 2 value UNION ALL SELECT 1,3 UNION ALL SELECT 1,4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,6 UNION ALL SELECT 3,7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,9 UNION ALL SELECT 5,10 
)
SELECT row[OFFSET(0)].* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1) row
  FROM `project.dataset.table_with_dups` t
  GROUP BY id
)
```

with result as

```sql
Row id  value    
1   1   4    
2   2   5    
3   3   7    
4   4   8    
5   5   10
```

As you can see it easily dedups table by `id` leaving row with largest value. Does not matter how many more other columns in that table  - above still works (it does not care of schema rather than id and value)

So, now, you can just use above SELECT and insert result into new table or overwrite original, etc. - all in one shot!

Comment: Can you clarify? What is the purpose of all the unions?

Comment: this are just to have some sample data - so you can run and see result by your own. for your use case you need just SELECT statement below WITH ... () . Updated answer to make it more clear -  Let me know if still confusion

Comment: Ok! My only question is what "value" is? The table is 400 columns in size, can I pick any as the value? Does it have to be unique? Can I pick the ID as the value? Thank you!

Comment: This is just arbitrary example that I put for you to play with and to see how you can control which row to survive. so in my example I used value to survive row with max value. in your example you can either totally ignore `ORDER BY value DESC` so in this case "random" row (off of those duplicate rows) will be chosen. Make sense?

Comment: so if to follow you exact example in question  - instead of `id` you should use `Unique_ID` and you should ignore that ORDER I mentioned in above comment. And of course you should use proper table reference.As I see you are most likely new to BigQuery  - try to be as close to my example/syntax as possible :o)

Comment: Thank you so much! Extremely helpful

Last question: Lets say one of those duplicates had a null value column "X", and the other had a populated value column "X". I want the row that has column "X" with a populated value to be the row that survives. How do I do that?

Comment: I did! did you see my last question?

Comment: ha-ha, that's exactly where that `ORDER BY ` is useful - use `ORDER BY X DESC` - so it will make sure to not to pick NULL value. Of course there can be more options depends on your specific use case. I recommend to complete this round - and if still some questions  - please ask/post new question :o)